# WPF Creating a multi use control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a WPF window that has a single control and 2 buttons displayed.
The control can be either a TextBox, ComboBox or Slider dependent on the type of object selected to launch this window.

Is it possible to do this or will I have to create a window with 3 conrtols and manipulate their position at runtime?

Regards

Tony

**additions to original question**

My implementation is as follows

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
            <Setter Value="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=m_csValue}" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate">
            <Setter Value="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=ItemsForSelection}" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Slider}" x:Key="SliderTemplate">
            <Setter Value="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=SliderDetail}" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="DisplayValues">
            <!-- Default Template -->
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=eType}" Value="{x:Static local:eTagDisplay.Text}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate Template="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter> 
                 </DataTrigger>
                <!-- DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=eType}" Value="{x:Static local:eTagDisplay.Combo}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=eType}" Value="{x:Static local:eTagDisplay.Slider}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate Template="{StaticResource SliderTemplate}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                </DataTrigger -->
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Width="267">
    <StackPanel Name="TagEditor1">
        <!-- Text="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=m_csValue}" / -->
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource DisplayValues}" />
    </StackPanel>


    <Button Content="OK" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,154,0,0" Name="btnOK" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="OnClkOK" />
    <Button Content="Cancel" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,154,0,0" Name="btnCancel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="OnClkCancel" IsCancel="True" />
</Grid>
```

I'm getting an error 'System.Windows.Style' is not a valid value for the 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.ContentTemplate' property on a setter. I don't know why this is happening.
My Binding is OK, i believe, as it picks up string OK....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with a `<ContentControl>` that has a different `<ContentTemplate>` depending on what type of control is needed.

You didn't specify how the control type is being passed to the window, so your `DataTrigger` bindings would probably look a bit different from mine, but this should give you the right idea:

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
    <TextBox ... />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate">
    <ComboBox ... />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="SliderTemplate">
    <Slider ... />
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <!-- Default Template -->
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" 
            Value="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBoundValue}" Value="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" 
                    Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBoundValue}" Value="Slider">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource SliderTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

...

<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" />
```

You could also allow users to specify a `Content` for your `UserControl` or `Window`, and simply display it using a `ContentPresenter` bound to the `Content`. Something like this:

```
<UserControl.Template>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        <Button ... />
        <Button ... />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl.Template>
```

then you could use it like this:

```
<local:MyUserControl>
    <TextBox ... />
</local:MyUserControl>

<local:MyUserControl>
    <ComboBox ... />
</local:MyUserControl>

<local:MyUserControl>
    <Slider ... />
</local:MyUserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is the sort of style I was looking for. As this type of thing is new to me, I am a bit confused as to how I integrate the XAML in to my main XAML body. I have added the Style information to the window.resources, but how do I use it within a <Grid> block. The decision as to which style to used will dependent on an integer passed to the window at creation time, e.g. if (Style == button) { controltype = button; } ? Thanks again

Comment: @maycockt The style is for a `ContentControl` so you would use `<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource MyContentControlStyle}" />` wherever you want your control to appear. You'd also have to modify the `DataTriggers` so they are based on the integer property that determines the style, such as `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=controltype}" Value="button">` (make sure `controltype` is a public property on the class)

Comment: @maycockt It's fine, we're all new once :)

Comment: That last comment was meant to read like this - Please excuse the spoonfeeding here.... I would then present it like this '<Grid> <Style as your first block of code /> <Button OK /> <Button Cancel /> </Grid>' if I just wanted 3 controls in my window? And my controltype as listed above is an enum, e.g. eType so the DataTrigger would be similar to '<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=StackPanel1, Path=eType}" Value="TextBox" />' if TextBox was declared as eType.TextBox if coded in c#?

Comment: @maycockt Close, you'll want to use a `<ContentControl>` instead of a `<Style>` in your previous comment. The `ContentControl` should apply the `Style`, and the `Style` should be found in the `.Resources` somewhere, such as  `<Window.Resources>`. Also, I think you need to use the actual enum value in the DataTrigger.Value, such as `Value="{x:Static local:eType.TextBox}"`. Otherwise it will probably return false since it will be trying to compare an object of type `eType` with a string value of `TextBox`. Also for your trigger to work, `StackPanel1` will need to have a property called `eType`

Comment: if I understand your last message, within my `<Window.Resources>` I have my `<Style>` information. Within my `<Grid>` I will have a `<ContentControl Style ="{StaticResource SomeStyle}" />` which leaves me to point to my style declared in the `<Window.Resources>` - how? (I have a hat with a 'D' on it ready for my corner seat)

Comment: @maycockt Sorry, I just noticed I forgot the `x:Key` property on the Style in my example. You need to give your style a `Key` so it can be referenced. For example, if I had `<Style x:Key="MyStyle" .../>` I could then write `<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" />`

Comment: _ i had to drop this for a couple of days, and have amended my original question. Any ideas what is wrong? Sorry - i'm posting this facing the wall with mu dunces cap on.....

Comment: @Tony See the edit to my answer. `ContentTemplate` should be a `DataTemplate`, not another `Style`

Comment: apart from needing to change `TargetType` to `DataType` in the `DataTemplate` sections that has now cracked it!!!! Thanks for your help, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible with single window.By exposing a property that sets visibilty based on some condition.
i.e textbox visibility is set to visibility.visible and combobox,slider visibilty is set to visibility.collpased.similarly if you want to have combobox visible you make that visible and others collapsed.similarly for slider.

example:

```
  public Visibility TextboxVisibility
    {
        set
        {
            Visibility visible = value;
            Textboxname.Visibility = visible ;
        }
    }
```

I hope this answers your question